# How to stop an MVC RedirectToRouteResult JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am designing a site and am trying to be compatible with javascript turned off or on.

I have a Controller Action named as follows...

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddWorkAssignment(int id)
{
    // delegate the work to add the work assignment...

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Assignment");
}
```

and my jQuery I do a post

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
    var id = $('#whereTheIDIs').val();
    $.post('/Assignment/AddWorkAssignment/' + id);
    return false;
});
```

but the RedirectToAction on the controller will do just that.... how do I stop the redirect to occur, or how do I structure the controller and page to handle this, because I want the redirect to occur if javascript is turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your controller to something like this:

```
public ActionResult AddWorkAssignment(int id)
{
    // do work to add the work assignment....

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Json(true);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Assignment");
}
```

You could create your own filter attribute too... much like the AcceptVerbs attribute.

HTHs
Charles

EDIT: AjaxRequest ActionMethodSelectorAttribute attribute

Kickstart from [here](http://helios.ca/2009/05/27/aspnet-mvc-action-filter-ajax-only-attribute/)

```
public class AjaxRequest : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");

        return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

Then your controller:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddWorkAssignment(int id)
{
    // do work to add the work assignment....

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Assignment");
}

[AjaxRequest]
public JsonResult AddWorkAssignment(int id)
{
    // do work to add the work assignment....

    return Json(true);
}
```